# getx controller cant routes to another page

Tags: flutter, controller, flutter-getx

please help to solve my que

when response of this post method is 200 is okay and in if statement do the work that i expected but when is 404 or 400 not worked.

i want when get 404 response route to another page but cant

and  tried all routes like navigator.push and get.to.

```
import 'package:bms/constant/api_constant.dart';
import 'package:bms/view/main/main_page.dart';
import 'package:bms/view/register/email_screen.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';




class AuthStep1Controler extends GetxController {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final Rx op = 0.0.obs;
  final RxBool visible = false.obs;
  checkEmail() async {
    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(ApiUrlConstant.checkEmail, data: {
        "email": emailController.text,
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 404) {
        Get.to(const EmailScreen());
      } else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          op.value = 1.0;
          visible.value = true;
        });
      } else if (response.statusCode == 400) {
        debugPrint(response.toString());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is DioException) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

 
}
```

Comment: Your 404 and 400 responses may be getting caught in the catch block. What does your  debug log show?

Comment: try Get.to( () => const YourPage());

Comment: @user2680414     DioMixin._dispatchRequest (c:\Users\Amin.kh\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\dio-5.3.0\lib\src\dio_mixin.dart:581)
<asynchronous gap> (Unknown Source:0)

Comment: @VivekChib   not worked i tried before

Comment: Use the code in https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors. When an error occurs, Dio will wrap the 404 to a DioException.